# How to specify what operations (Http Methods) is available with HATEOAS

Tags: rest, authorization, restful-architecture, restful-url, hateoas

The HATEOAS definition say that each response must contains the associated links, but following the REST pattern an URI must be the same for all operations, what changes is the HTTP method.

Per example:

Request: GET http://example.com/book

Response:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title:" "foo",
    "links": {
      "self": http://example.com/book/1
    }
  }
]
```

The response inform that the link that can be used to read the book data is "http://example.com/book/1", but with only this link i unknown if the user that did this request is authorized to do a DELETE or PUT for this resource.

The HATEOAS or other specification define some pattern for inform what methods are available for each resource?

Per example:

Request: GET http://example.com/book

Response:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title:" "foo",
    "links": {
      "self": {
        "url": "http://example.com/book/1",
        "methods": [
          "GET",
          "PUT",
          "DELETE"
        ]
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look for Siren (http://hyperschema.org/mediatypes/siren)
It will tell your clients what methods do they can use with links.